# SQL Update Query With Specific Conditions

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g database and have two tables:

**`EMP`**

```
ID  EMPNO   AGE DATE_PUBLISHED

1   1001    11  14/01/1999

2   1002    22  14/01/1999

3   1003    33  14/01/1999

4   1004    44  14/01/1999

5   1005    55  14/01/1999

6   1006    66  14/01/1999
```

**`EMP_MIRROR`**

```
ID  EMPNO   AGE DATE_PUBLISHED

1   1001    11  05/01/2004

2   1123    54  05/01/2004

3   1003    87  05/01/2004

4   1004    65  05/01/2004

5   1545    78  05/01/2004

6   1006    14  05/01/2004
```

I want to update the `DATE_PUBLISHED` column of the `EMP_MIRROR` table based on the following condition:

If for any `ID` in both the tables, there is a difference in the values of `EMPNO` or `AGE`, then the `DATE_PUBLISHED` column of `EMP_MIRROR` should be updated to `SYSDATE`.

**`EMP_MIRROR (after updation)`**

```
ID  EMPNO   AGE DATE_PUBLISHED

1   1001    11  05/01/2004

2   1123    54  07/07/2014

3   1003    87  07/07/2014

4   1004    65  07/07/2014

5   1545    78  07/07/2014

6   1006    14  07/07/2014
```

Explanation for the result set:

```
ID: 1 (EMPNO and AGE are same in both the tables, hence DATE_PUBLISHED is not updated)

ID: 2 (EMPNO and AGE are different in both the tables, hence DATE_PUBLISHED is updated)

ID: 3 (AGE is different in both the tables, hence DATE_PUBLISHED is updated)

ID: 4 (AGE is different in both the tables, hence DATE_PUBLISHED is updated)

ID: 5 (EMPNO and AGE are different in both the tables, hence DATE_PUBLISHED is updated)

ID: 6 (AGE is different in both the tables, hence DATE_PUBLISHED is updated)
```

Please suggest a query which can achieve this result.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: given you are referencing SYSDATE, i am assuming oracle, please add this tag.

Answer (score 0):

The standard SQL Solution for this (since no DBMS Specified) would be:

```
UPDATE  EMP_MIRROR
SET     DATE_PUBLISHED = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1 
            FROM    EMP
            WHERE   EMP.ID = EMP_MIRROR.ID
            AND (   EMP.AGE <> EMP_MIRROR.AGE
                OR  EMP.EMPNO <> EMP_MIRROR.EMPNO
                )
        );
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e5d7d/1)**

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE emp_mirror
SET    date_published = SYSDATE
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM   emp
              WHERE  emp.id = emp_mirror.id
              AND  ((emp.age != emp_mirror.age OR)
                    (emp.empno != emp_mirror.empno)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with temp as(
select [ID]
       ,[DATE_PUBLISHED]

from [EMP_MIRROR]
inner join [EMP] on [EMP_MIRROR].[ID] = [EMP].[ID]

where [EMP_MIRROR].[DATE_PUBLISHED] <> [EMP].[DATE_PUBLISHED]
)

update [EMP_MIRROR] set [DATE_PUBLISHED] = GETDATE() where ID = (Select [ID] from temp)
```

There's probably a better way to do this, but if you were to compare the two tables and then select the IDs where the date does not match into a temp table, then use an update on that new list of IDs.

Just FYI, I haven't checked if this statement works yet, but the gist of it is there, I'll update it when I've had time to test it.

Comment: Checking through the answers now posted, GarethD's Solution is much more efficient :)

Answer (score 0):

May be Something  like this

```
With CTE AS 
(
 SELECT EM.* FROM EMP_MIRROR EM JOIN EMP E ON E.ID = EM.ID
 WHERE EM.AGE <> E.AGE OR E.EMPNO <> EM.EMPNO 
)
Update EMP_MIRROR EE SET DATE_PUBLISHED = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
FROM CTE JOIN EMP_MIRROR ON CTE.EMPNO = EE.EMPNO
```